# Composing measures: What does this notation from Durrett's probability book mean?

Tags: probability, notation, definition

In Durrett's book "[Probability: Theory and Examples](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)" (pg. 32), he states the following change of variables formula:

> Let $X$ be a random element of $(S,\mathcal{S})$ with distribution $\mu$, i.e., $\mu(A) = P(X\in A)$.  If $f$ is a measurable function from $(S,\mathcal{S})$ to $(\textbf{R},\mathcal{R})$ so that $f\geq 0$ or $E|f(X)|<\infty$, then $$Ef(X) = \int_S f(y)\mu(dy)$$

As far as I can tell, he never defines the notation $\mu(dy)$.  **What does this notation mean?**

Comment: $\int_S f(y)\mu(dy) = \int_S f(y) d\mu(y)$ (maybe you saw that notation in the second form). It just means the integral with respect to $\mu$ measure.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_S f(y) \mu(dy)$$
is simply the integral of $f$ against the measure $\mu$ with respect to the variable $y$.

You may also see the other notations $\int_S f d\mu$ or $\int_S f(y) d\mu(y)$.